# Eclipse won't print the blank spaces in my code

Tags: java, eclipse

My problem is with the very centre while loop. The goal of the program is to print a box made of asterisks with the specified dimensions provided by the user, and it works fairly well. However, the centre while loop will not print the white spaces to distance itself.

What could be causing this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class bonus {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner widthScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the width: ");
        int width = widthScan.nextInt();

        Scanner heightScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the height: ");
        int height = heightScan.nextInt();

        int resetWidth = width;
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////opening width sandwich
        while(width>=1)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
            width--;
        }
        System.out.println();
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        int specialHeight = height-2;
        int specialWidth = width-2;
        while(specialHeight>=1)
        {
            System.out.print("*");

            while(specialWidth>=1)
            {
                System.out.println(" ");
                specialWidth--;
            }

            System.out.print("*");
            specialHeight--;
            System.out.println();
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        while(resetWidth>=1)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
            resetWidth--;
        }
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////closing width sandwich
    }
}
```

Comment: You are changing the width value, then reusing it as if it was unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

After this loop:

```
while(width>=1)
```

`width` is clearly 0 or less.

Next you do:

```
int specialWidth = width-2;
```

So `specialWidth` is -2 or less.

You then have:

```
while(specialWidth>=1)
```

How would you *expect* to ever enter that loop? What do you *expect* `specialWidth` to be? It's not clear how you intended `specialWidth` to be initialized (perhaps the initial value of `width`?) but that's probably the place to look.

Now would also be a good time to learn to use a debugger, so you can step through the code to work out what's going on, if you can't do it by inspection.

Answer (score 0):

Well on your `opening width sandwich` you are doing a while loop that decreases `width` until is zero

Then you calculate `specialWidth = width-2` which is negative always. 
Your `middle while` will not happen.